# How can I use boto to generate pre-signed POST requests for a bucket with KMS-managed encryption keys?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

Amazon's blog post describes using the Java client to [generate pre-signed URLs for buckets with SSE-KMS encryption](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/generating-amazon-s3-pre-signed-urls-with-sse-kms-part-2/), but it's not clear how to do the same with `boto3`.

How can I use boto to generate pre-signed POST requests for a bucket with KMS-managed encryption keys?

Answer (score 1):

After some experimentation, this method seems to work.

Some notes:

- The `region_name` must be specified if the bucket is not in `us-east-1`
- The bucket's default encryption key will be used. To specify a key, use `x-amz-server-side-encryption-customer-key`.

```py
import boto3
from botocore.client import Config as BotoConfig

s3 = boto3.client(
    "s3",
    aws_access_key_id=Config.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
    aws_secret_access_key=Config.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
    config=BotoConfig(
        region_name="us-west-2", # Note: required when region is not us-east-1
        signature_version="s3v4",
    ),
)

res = s3.generate_presigned_post(
    Bucket=Config.AWS_S3_BUCKET_NAME,
    Key=some_key,
    Fields={
        "x-amz-server-side-encryption": "aws:kms",
    },
    Conditions=[
        ["starts-with", "$Content-Type", "image/"], # for example
        ["content-length-range", 0, 1024 * 1024 * 12], # for example
        {"x-amz-server-side-encryption": "aws:kms"},
    ],
)
```